# Need help in youtube video bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, youtube, download, inline

I'm making a web app and a bookmarklets for my website so that user can directly bookmark any video in their browser through any youtube video posted on my website.

hi anyone can help me to solve this for **youtube video bookmarklets**

I want to keep only youtube video ID in following code

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://example.com/bookmarklets/bookmark?id='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'')})();
```

Result should be : **http://example.com/bookmarklets/bookmark?id=LIQZ6CjpHUA**

but when i test above code i found that it takes whole youtube URL instead of youtube video ID

**Instead of above result i got this : **http://example.com/bookmarklets/bookmark?id=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUeqywml0SU**

**but i want only this result : http://example.com/bookmarklets/bookmark?IUeqywml0SU**

Comment: Snorting cocaïn is illegal even if you did not make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers by myself...

> here are the code

**When we'll use this bookmarklet**

> ```
> javascript:(function(){window.open('http://example.com/download/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'?id='+encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', ''))+'')})();
> ```

**For this youtube video**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhQGm9d4e8c
```

**We'll get this final output from URL:**

```
GhQGm9d4e8c
```

Thanks